# Firebase query to find limtToLast(1) by user_id_2 where user_id_1 == 1

Tags: firebase

[image: This is my data structure in firebase database and my Srcipt file.[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro1PJ.png)

I'm fetching data from this Srcipt file.And I'm not able to find any query to get limitToLast(1) by user_id_2 where user_id_1 = 1 or any specific given digit.
Note : var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://*****.firebaseio.com/mails');
is written, neglect this syntax in photo.

Comment: multiple query not supported by firebase. you can take 'user_id_1'=1 list and get last item of the list in client side. If mail addresses are too much, the solution is not good for you. Maybe you should change your data structure. Post it here if you wish and we can discuss..

Comment: Thank you, I changed my data structure.